# How do i install dotnetCoreApp1.1 to project created in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.0

I have project created in `Visual Studio 2013.`

Recently, we have `VS2013` with `VS2017`.
I want to change `.Net Framework` from `4.5` to `DotNetCore 1.1`

I go to `Project Properties` window and can see only `Target Framework` until `4.6.1.`

I dont see `DotNetCoreApp1.1?` **Why**?

I clicked on Install Other frameworks option and navigated to Microsoft Page where i can see

[image]

I am not sure which one i should take ? 
Anyways, i clicked  .Net Core SDK.
An installer came up and installed

> But option still doesnot show DotNetCoreApp1.1?
>
> I believe when i installed VS2017, DotNetCore1.1 framework should have
>   been auto installed.

Comment: You need to create a new set of projects targeting .NET Core and copy over the files (or move the newly created csproj into your old project). .NET Core uses a new csproj structure and old csproj files won't be recognized as .NET Core compatible

Comment: Yes @Tseng, more difference for older & new csproj structure in dotnet. Mr simbada once you installed VS 2017 then you can create Asp.Net Core 1.0 & 1.1 Apps.

Comment: No need to create new project set. You can modify `.csproj` directly to target `netcoreapp1.1`.

Comment: @tchelidze That will only change framework from 4.6.1 to netcoreapp1.1. That will not change the project structure e.g. .net core doesn't maintain Project.json anymore

Comment: @Tseng seems the correct and better way

Comment: @simbada yeah, `project.json` is no longer maintained, but what ?

Comment: .NET Core 1.1 (csproj) is only supported in Visual Studio 2017 (Or Rider/VS Code etc if you prefer). VS2013 is not going to work.